# Creating an app that will display what apps you currently have installed

Tags: java, android

My question is pretty simple.  I have created several apps that tell me what sensors I have and also to display the data, Accelerometer, GPS, etc... One thing I am trying to do is to create an app that will display what apps my phone currently has on it.  I looked around online but have not come up with any way to do this.  Is this a permission issue?  anyway to do this?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a sample application a while ago that displays a list of currently installed applications. It uses `getInstalledApplications()` as Commonsware suggests. You can find a link to the application's source code in this [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/09/tutorial-loader-loadermanager.html).

Answer (score 0):

> anyway to do this?

Use `PackageManager`, and [methods like `getInstalledApplications()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29).